# SAPUI5 oData Error! FK 80 - RFC-Error: End date xx.xx.xxxx is earlier than start date yy.yy.yyyy

Tags: odata, sapui5

Having an entity with a date field inserted/updated via a SAPUI5 dialog. After some consecutive updates (changes on the date via the datepicker) on the same record, I experience this weird error. I say weird because I don't have this kind of check inside my update entity. In fact the update entity method does nothing more than performing a couple of simple checks in other fields and eventually inserting the record, no calls to BAPIs, standard SAP function modules or anything. Also weird the fact that it doesn't happen always. Spent half the day repeating the same motif, just consecutive updates with debug, sometimes it happens, sometimes not. No exception occurs in my method, error comes from standard SAP after the end of get_entityset which follows the update. If helpful, I attach a snapshot of the batch operations involved.

[Batch operations table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4tFi.jpg)

And it gets better! After the application crashes, never opens again, it actually produces during the load of the initial worklist (get_entityset method) a variation of the aforementioned error (Message E FK 080 cannot be processed in plugin mode HTTPS). Application stops crashing...as soon as I delete the record from the database.

Record looks just fine in SE16N and gateway client works fine when I test the get_entityset method. Cleared all cache in the system (used this: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/03/02/cache-maintenance-in-fiori/), cleared even the browser cache (yeah, I know that doesn't make sense) but problem persists. I use model.submitChanges to update, no change groups involved.

Does this ring any bells to anyone?

Best regards

Greg

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a running example in a tool like https://plnkr.co/  ?
This might be helpful in debugging the issue.

Comment: @SAP Fiori Crew: unfortunately don't think I can do that. It's not only that I don't know the tool, has to do also with the fact that, even though I didn't get any error debugging the backend methods, the error is reported as a backend error and I don't think that I can recreate my model there. What I've done after day one is creating an incident (priority M) in SAP support portal and I just hope that someone will deal with it. Thanks however for offering to help.

Comment: Maybe the following transactions in the ABAP backend help to identify the issue:
- SM21
- STRFCTRACE
- ST03N 

Could it be a temporary network issue?

Comment: @SAP Fiori Crew: Looks like it's not with a first look. Tried both in the dev (personal web IDE) and the deployed edition (in the same system with the oData model), error consistent only when this date field involved, just a question of how many updates. However I will have a look there as well - thanks ;-)

PS: just got an "We are currently investigating the issue" response to the SAP incident raised, would like to believe that something will be found there